# Error initializing mysql

Tags: kubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to install and set up mysql on my kubuntu 16.04. But when I run `bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql` I get the following error message:

```
mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysql/data/' (Errcode: 2 -No such file or directory)
2017-02-16T20:49:13.608398Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-02-16T20:49:13.608691Z 0 [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/usr/local/mysql/share/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2017-02-16T20:49:13.610794Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why are you running that command? Doesn't `sudo service mysql start` work?

Comment: "mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysql/data/"  there is no /usr/local/mysql I would assume. Don't think it is a default mysql directory though so check your config file? :-)

Comment: Did you simply try typing `mysql` with a user name and password?

Comment: Realized I should've written a lot more info, sorry about that. I should 
start with saying I'm a mysql newbie with VERY limited knowledge.

What i tried to do was to set mysql up according to these instructions and i was on step 4.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html

I tried just now to start the service but got an error saying: 

fredrik@garnbutik:~$ sudo service mysql start
[sudo] password for fredrik: 
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm trying to find that file but I'm stuck. Where do i find it?

Comment: mysql.service isn't a file; it is a service.did you perhaps install mariadb? :)

Comment: @Rinzwind i'm not that new :) i meant i was trying to find the config file to check the default directory.

Comment: ah darn :D do  a `locate my.cnf` and the general options should be in `/etc/apache*/`